# How to pass scope variables into a directive when restrict: class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

What is the syntax for passing a variable into a scope when using directives as classes?

Say, I have a directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('revealOverlay', ['$state', '$window',
  function ($state, $window) {
    return {
      scope: {
        cancelStateName: "=?"
      },
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function (scope, element) {
        if (scope.cancelStateName == undefined) { scope.cancelStateName = ".^" }
        element.on('click', function (e) {
          $state.go(scope.cancelStateName)
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Where the `link` sets a default for canceStateName when it is not passed in. What that cancelStateName does exactly, or how it's used is not very relevant for the issue here.

So, when I use this directive, how would I assign a `cancelStateName` to it?

I tried

```
<aside class="reveal-overlay" cancel-state-name="xxx">...</aside>
```

or

```
<aside class="reveal-overlay: { cancelStateName: 'xxx'} ">...</aside>
```

but neither seem to work. I cannot find any documentation on how to pass in variables for the scope when using the "class syntax".

Comment: There is no difference on parsing params into directive based on different `restrict` types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example should work. When you use `restrict: C` on a directive, you can pass bindings in via additional tags.

Assuming a controller like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.directiveTitle = "Title for directive";
});
```

And a view and directive like this:

```
<div class="test-directive" title="directiveTitle"></div>

app.directive('testDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      title: '='
    },
    restrict: "C",
    template: '<div>{{title}}</div>'
  };
});
```

Here is an example plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/HaYkxbWBlbzL1YcNrtBZ

A variant of your second example can also work, if you set up the directive properly:

```
<div class="test-directive: directiveTitle"></div>

app.directive('testDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      title: '=testDirective'
    },
    restrict: "C",
    template: '<div>{{title}}</div>'
  };
});
```

A plunker for this: https://plnkr.co/edit/vEy7htKpRXzWdYU9W9qo